# Permission Issue with Docker Volume Driver for Azure File Storage

Tags: unix, azure, docker

I am following the readme for this project (https://github.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver/blob/master/contrib/init/upstart/README.md), but when I try and mount a volume on a container like this

```
docker volume create -d azurefile -o share=myshare --name=myvol
docker run -i -t -v myvol:/data busybox
(inside the container)
# cd /data
# touch file.txt
```

I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: VolumeDriver.Mount: mount failed: exit status 32
output="mount.cifs kernel mount options:    ip=168.61.57.82,unc=\\\\cmstoragecd.file.core.windows.net\\myshare,vers=3.0,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,user=cmstoragecd,pass=********\nmount 
error(13): Permission denied\nRefer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)\n"
```

This is running on an Ubuntu 14.04 server on Azure. I have successfully used the extension with similiar servers, but it is now not working. What can I do to debug this?

Comment: Dan, we suggest opening issues at https://github.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver/issues in the future. We do not offer support for this project on GitHub (I just randomly came across your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your answer is correct. CIFS in many Linux distros currently do not have encryption support ––which Azure File Storage requires in cross-region SMB traffic.

Quoting the note at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-how-to-use-files-linux/

> **Note:** The Linux SMB client doesn’t yet support encryption, so mounting a file share from Linux still requires that the client be in the same Azure region as the file share. However, encryption support for Linux is on the roadmap of Linux developers responsible for SMB functionality. Linux distributions that support encryption in the future will be able to mount an Azure File share from anywhere as well.

In the future, please consider directly contacting to us by opening a new issue on our GitHub repository at: https://github.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver/issues.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this error by using a storage account in the same region as the Azure VM. Originally I had a VM running in West Europe, using a file share in East US.